# Wellsortedness error ... not of sort equal

Tags: isabelle

Here is a trivial translator from language `foo` to `bar`:

```
type_synonym vname = "string"
type_synonym 'a env = "vname ⇒ 'a option"

datatype foo_exp = FooBConst bool
datatype foo_type = FooBType | FooIType | FooSType

datatype bar_exp = BarBConst bool
datatype bar_type = BarBType | BarIType

fun foo_to_bar_type :: "foo_type ⇒ bar_type option" where
  "foo_to_bar_type FooBType = Some BarBType" |
  "foo_to_bar_type FooIType = Some BarIType" |
  "foo_to_bar_type _ = None"

inductive foo_to_bar :: "foo_type env ⇒ foo_exp ⇒ bar_type env ⇒ bar_exp ⇒ bool" where
"Γ⇩B = map_comp foo_to_bar_type Γ⇩F ⟹
 foo_to_bar Γ⇩F (FooBConst c) Γ⇩B (BarBConst c)"

code_pred [show_modes] foo_to_bar .

values "{t. foo_to_bar Map.empty (FooBConst True) Map.empty t}"
```

The last line causes the following error:

```
Wellsortedness error
(in code equation foo_to_bar_i_i_i_o ?x ?xa ?xb ≡
                  Predicate.bind (Predicate.single (?x, ?xa, ?xb))
                   (λ(Γ⇩F_, aa, Γ⇩B_).
                       case aa of
                       FooBConst c_ ⇒
                         Predicate.bind (eq_i_i Γ⇩B_ (foo_to_bar_type ∘⇩m Γ⇩F_))
                          (λ(). Predicate.single (BarBConst c_))),
with dependency "Pure.dummy_pattern" -> "foo_to_bar_i_i_i_o"):
Type char list ⇒ bar_type option not of sort equal
No type arity list :: enum
```

Could you suggest me how to fix it?

Also `foo_to_bar` has mode `i => i => o => o => boolpos`. How should I execute `values` to generate both 3rd and 4th arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general I'd advise against using `inductive` to define something that can easily be expressed as a function. While the predicate compiler comes with a lot of bells and whistles to make computational sense of an inductive definition, there are a lot of problems that can arise because it's so complex. In your case, the problem lies in the line

```
Γ⇩B = map_comp foo_to_bar_type Γ⇩F
```

You are trying to compare two functions. The predicate compiler doesn't know that it can be seen as a "defining equation". In a sense, you're asking the predicate compiler to solve an impossible problem.

Your life will be much easier if `foo_to_bar` is defined as a function (or plain definition) instead. It'll work out of the box with the code generator.